# Why does my name@mydomain.com Gmail account still works when mydomain.com is now off?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

For many years I had a .com domain and an email account with that domain name which I consulted using Gmail. Today this domain is unavailable because I cancelled it, yet I can still consult my email address on Gmail and the G Suite account I have with that email address also still works.

Why or how do they still work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internet domain names are pointers that tell were the Internet traffic should be delivered. For more details please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name.

Gmail and G Suite "still works" because you are using the Google URLs not the customize urls with your domain. It's very likely that if someone send an email to your email address it will not be delivered and your data could be lost if someone else buy the domain and use it for G Suite.

Comment: You're right I can't receive emails to that address (can send from it though), I just checked. Thanks! Would you happen to know whether it's possible then to replace this old email address with a new one in G Suite? (I know it's a completely different question) –